# What can I use to automate actions in another program's UI?

Tags: windows, automation, user-interface

I need to automate the manipulation of a Windows application's user interface.  That is, I am looking for recommendations for software that is capable of typing things into, and clicking on the buttons of, another application's "user interface".

I need this software to be capable of working from data I've provided to it. The application I will be manipulating (using whatever software is recommended here) has thousands of customer records in it.  I need to be able to give the software a list of all our customers and have it type those customer names/numbers into the appropriate textboxes of the target window, then click on the search button to find that customer, and then proceed with additional tasks on the "customer" screen.

UI testing software, such as Ranorex, TestStack/White, and Test Complete have come to my attention through Google searches, but having no experience with any of them, I do not know if they will actually do what I need (as described above).  I am also interested to know, from others' experience, if there are better ideas than the ones I've found on my own.

<sup>The original writeup of this question can be found [in the revision history](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/10624/revisions).</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate the operation of the a GUI driven application in a number of ways one of which is [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) it differs from a lot of such tools by using image recognition to find the buttons to press, etc.

- Free
- Open Source
- Windows, Mac and Linux
- Not a problem if the window position changes
- No need to try to find out the control identifiers in the GUI
- Java based
- Scriptable in python or ruby